# What the CMD commands (Like build,new port,http-server) for angular without using CLI?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am not able to use direct CLI commands in my system.

Commands like `ng serve` are working while others like `ng serve --port 5000` and `http-server` are not.

The error says:

> A complete log of this run can be found in:

This listed my user's folder path, but that path was not visible in my system.

Are there any commands for angular installation and deployment without using Angular CLI?

Comment: I take it you can use npm but nothing else?

Comment: Actually i installed Angular CLI in globally but while use commands like "ng serve" it says like "ng serve is not recognized as an internal or external command" , in that case what i have to do ? kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Points need to check :
1. Have you done the global installation of Angular CLI ? using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

2. is this project is created using `ng new` command?
3. Check the scripts in the `package.json` file.